# Is it possible to have an OpenGL canvas within a window of a website?

Tags: angular, web, opengl

I have made several OpenGL programs and would like to run them on a website.

I understand that OpenGL is just for rendering 2D or 3D vector graphics, communicating with the GPU. So, can I only run the programs locally, in the GLFWWindow?
I have looked online and all I've seen is that it can only be ran locally. After working with P5.js, I was hoping there was a way to create a "canvas" for an OpenGL program and put them in an angular website I created.

Answer (score 0):

[WebGL is a thing](https://get.webgl.org/). It's essentially OpenGL-ES wrapped up in a JavaScript API.

There's also [OpenGL support in Emscripten](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/multimedia_and_graphics/OpenGL-support.html) which essentially piggybacks in WebGL. Emscripten also supports GLFW.